# Run a java main class from JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, swing, jsp

This is how my java main class looks like

```
     public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XmlParser b = new XmlParser();

    ServiceController sl = new ServiceController();

    Pipeline2 objPipeline2 = new Pipeline2();

    objPipeline2.main(args);

    b.parseXML();

    sl.callServiceByDomain();

}

public void function1() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello");

}
```

Here is the run.jsp file where i want to run the main function

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="main.Main" %>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Enter Email over here</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "main.Main" />   
  <%Main r=new Main();
  Main.main(null);%>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am not able to run it if i am running the run.jsp file where as if i am trying to run the function1 from the jsp in place of main....it is running. please help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

The main method accepts a parameter (`String[] args`). Try `<%r.main(null);%>` if you are not interested in passing any parameters.

BTW, `main` is static, so `<%Main.main(null);%>` should also work, and is the preferred way of calling a static method (i.e. without creating an instance of `Main`).

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /run.jsp at line 9


type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /run.jsp at line 9

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /run.jsp at line 9 i.e Main.main(null);
<BODY>
<jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class = "main.Main" />   
  <% Main r=new Main();
  Main.main(null);
  %>
</BODY>
 </HTML>

Comment: @user3324788 Your import `<%@ page import="java.io.*,main.Main" %>` is strange. Which package does Main class belong to? Try `<%@ page import="java.io.*" %><%@ page import="packageofmainclass.Main" %>`

Comment: the package is 'main' and tried in the way you said but its the same error again

Comment: @user3324788 I tried something similar (running a main method from a JSP), and it worked. Can you edit your question with the full code of the JSP with the changes I suggested? Perhaps you have some syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @user3324788 I think the `<jsp:useBean>` tag should be before the `<HTML>` tag, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: If i add the tag <jsp:useBean> before the HTML tag, this is what it showed  HTTP Status 500 - /run.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) UseBean: Mandatory attribute id missing

Comment: @user3324788 I meant you should move your existing `<jsp:useBean id=...` tag from its current location to before the HTML tag, not add a new empty `<jsp:useBean>` tag.