# how can I run a jar from JSP tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jar

I created a simple jar (helloword.jar) that prints "Hello World", i want to run it from my JSP web page that is running in an apache-tomcat server. The file helloword.jar is in the same porject/folder that contains my JSP page.

This is my code for the JSP and it is not showing the message "Hello World" in the tomcat console nor web-broswer console. (I imported the jar in the libraries in my NetBeans IDE)

```
<%@ page import="helloword.*" %>
<%
        helloword hw = new helloword();
        hw.main();

               %>
```

I tried this too but it didnt work neither.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar helloword.jar");
```

Comment: put the jar into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350621/run-a-java-main-class-from-jsp.Main method requires String array as argument.

Comment: *How* does it "print" the string?

Comment: To print values please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085976/is-there-a-way-to-call-java-class-with-main-from-jsp-and-print-the-value-in-th

Answer (score 0):

While creating the jar , write a method other than main 
for example

```
public static void display()
{
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

step1: put the jar in web-inf lib folder.
step2: import jar in page tag.
step3: call this method directly by class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute jar dynamically, you need to add jar to jvm context, then create and instance of Main class, and then run main method.

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJar.toURL(), this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class clazz = Class.forName ("com.MyClass", true, child);
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName", String.class);
Object o = method.invoke(null, "whatever");
```